# Why Google search result page has an "Ad Added" + number on the title of the result page?

Tags: google-search

I have encountered this situation a few times, it's not happening every time, and finally, I got this screenshot:

[image]

It's not just happening for my Chrome, but also for my brand-new installed Safari:

[image]

I even tried SERP checker. It's still the same:

[image]

Has anyone seen this before? What is this for?